# How to Fix TimeStamp?

Tags: timestamp, spreadsheet

Is there any way to fix timestamp data without scripting.
i am using formula to fix timestamp data my status column is D2 and active timestamp on D1--=now()

=if(D2,D2,if(D2<>"",$D$1,"")

but timestamp is fluctuating when status column is update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell D2. You can drag it down as needed.
The way it works is if cell C2 is empty and cell D2 does not already have a timestamp (empty) then when cell C2 get any value cell D2 will get a timestamp.

```
=IFS($C2="","",$D2="",now(),TRUE,$D2)
```